# Click the button to open the URL in the Application

Tags: android, android-layout

My problem is this, I created a button that calls by clicking a URL page, and when I click it opens the browser. I wish the same to open within the application itself. Can someone help me ?

**Main Activity.java**

```
public void btnSite (View View) {

    String url = "http://google.com.br/";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

What setting do I use to open within the application?

Comment: Use English only on SO

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not in English. Please translate the question or use Stack Overflow en español http://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's not Spanish, my bad

Comment: Portuguese actually but the issue's the same, it's still off topic. Google Translate did a good job on this post; I edited on his behalf with the new text, it should show up once reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider a WebView. See the below for documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

There are some limitations on what this'll do though (e.g. in terms of JavaScript and error handling), see the documentation for details and ways to overcome that.